# I want my Firefox to type "," instead of "." on my number block

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, localization, iceweasel

I live in Germany and here "," is the decimal separator. So, when I use Firefox I would like to have "," on the number block when I use online banking (or similar) so that I can properly use that key.

When I googled this question I only found forum links with links to dead links and a "thank you". So I know it must work somehow, yet I don't know how exactly.

I have a Debian and the packages:

```
ii  iceweasel                                38.3.0esr-1~deb8u1                  amd64        Web browser based on Firefox
ii  iceweasel-l10n-de                        1:38.3.0esr-1~deb8u1                all          German language package for Iceweasel
```

I have set the preferences to display pages in German first (other preferred languages contain English).

I use the keyboard setting "Dvorak DE".

In other programs (like gnumeric) I have a "," on that key so it must be possible to change that per application.

Comment: I don't think you can do this per application, at least not directly, but do have a look at `xmodmap`. You can use that tool to dump the current keyboard layout as well as adjust it. For an answer taking into account the desktop environment you are using (most of them provide more user-friendly ways of doing the same thing), you will have to specify which DE you are using.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I concur. In gnumeric I have a "," not a "." - That means its at least possible. I edited this into my question. I would be willing to change the language of the system as well if necessary (and I know how)